# Sort list by eventually existing value

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sorting, nhibernate

I have to sort a given list by a value which may or may not be given inside another list of each element. If no value is given, this element should appear at the bottom of the sorted list.

Here's a short example: I want to sort the list `Items` based on the `Value` of the `Property` which has the name `foo`

```cs
public class Item {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

List<Item> items = new List<Item>() {
    new Item() {
        Name = "Item 1",
        Properties = new List<Property>() {
            new Property {
                Name = "foo",
                Value = 5
            },
            new Property {
                Name = "bar",
                Value = 7
            }
        }
    },
    new Item() {
        Name = "Item 2",
        Properties = new List<Property>() {
            new Property {
                Name = "bar",
                Value = 2
            }
        }
    },
    new Item() {
        Name = "Item 3",
        Properties = new List<Property>() {
            new Property {
                Name = "foo",
                Value = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

The sorted list should contain the `Item`s in the order `Item 1`, `Item 3`, `Item 2`

I tried this:

```cs
items.FetchOrderBy
(
    x => x.Properties
    .FirstOrDefault
    (
        y => y.Name = "foo"
    )
    .Value
)
.ToList();
```

...But got the following exception: `Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `FetchOrderBy`.  Is that a method you wrote?  If so, can we see it?

Comment: FetchOrderBy() is a method by NHibernate. But you are right: Fetch().OrderBy() solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when there's no property match, `FirstOrDefault` returns null.  You could get around this by using a null-coalescing operator:

```
items.FetchOrderBy
(
    x => (x.Properties
    .FirstOrDefault
    (
        y => y.Name == "foo"
    )
    // Send non-matches to the bottom
    ?? new Property { Value = Int32.MaxValue })
    .Value
)
.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks! I have to apolagize because your suggestion also produced the same error.
 
I just substitute FetchOrderBy() by Fetch().OrderBy() and everthing was fine..